# Created Signup Page for my project and used User model but after signing in the data is not getting saved in admin

Tags: python, django

Trying to create Signup Page and store the details of user in User model but the data is not getting saved.I have imported the User model in forms.py.Below is the code of forms.py and view which is created.

Views.py

```
 from .forms import SignUpForm,LoginForm,PostForm
 def user_signup(request):
    if request.method=="POST":

    form = SignUpForm(request.POST)  
    if form.is_valid():
        un=form.cleaned_data['username']
        fn=form.cleaned_data['first_name']
        ln=form.cleaned_data['last_name']
        em=form.cleaned_data['email']
        var=User(username=un,first_name=fn,last_name=ln,email=en)
        var.save()
        form = SignUpForm()

    else:
        form= SignUpForm()



    return render(request,'Blog/signup.html',{'form':form})
```

forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):

     password1=forms.CharField(label='Password',widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
     password2=forms.CharField(label='Password Again',widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
     class Meta:
         model = User
         fields=['username','first_name','last_name','email']
         labels={
        'first_name':'First Name',
        'last_name':'Last Name',
        'email':'Email'
       }



     
       widgets={
          'username':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
          'first_name':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
          'last_name':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
          'email':forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'})
         }
```

Comment: Please provide more details as to what files are having issues and what parts of the code are meant to refernce this with comments or a more detailed description.
Additional help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

If you are using save for the first time, you might have to use `force_insert=True`:

```
if form.is_valid():
    un=form.cleaned_data['username']
    fn=form.cleaned_data['first_name']
    ln=form.cleaned_data['last_name']
    em=form.cleaned_data['email']
    var=User(username=un,first_name=fn,last_name=ln,email=en)
    var.save(force_insert=True)
    form = SignUpForm()
```

Or,

Directly save from the form:

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    un=form.cleaned_data['username']
    fn=form.cleaned_data['first_name']
    ln=form.cleaned_data['last_name']
    em=form.cleaned_data['email']
    form = SignUpForm()
```

Or,
Use `create()` which is specifically used to `insert` in data:

```
if form.is_valid():
    un=form.cleaned_data['username']
    fn=form.cleaned_data['first_name']
    ln=form.cleaned_data['last_name']
    em=form.cleaned_data['email']
    User.objects.create(username=un,first_name=fn,last_name=ln,email=en)
    form = SignUpForm()
```